# How to set end condition of string iterator in C++?

Tags: string, c++11, for-loop, iterator

i'm new in C++. I met a problem when doing exercise in C++ Primer 5th edition(Ex 9.43). The for loop can't stop in my function find_and_replace. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int find_and_replace(std::string& org_str, const std::string& str4find, const std::string& str4replace);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::string str("I am a very loooooong string to be process!");
    int find_times;
    find_times = find_and_replace(str, "a", "###");
    std::cout << find_times << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int find_and_replace(std::string& org_str, const std::string& str4find, const std::string& str4replace)
{
    int find_times = 0;

    if (org_str.size() < str4find.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: The original string is too short!" << std::endl;
        return find_times;
    }
    else if (org_str == str4find)
    {
        org_str.assign(str4replace);
        ++find_times;
        return find_times;
    }

    for (auto i = org_str.begin(), j = i + str4find.size(); j != org_str.end(); )
    {
        std::string temp(i, j);
        // std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        if (temp == str4find)
        {
            j = org_str.erase(i, j);
            org_str.insert(i, str4replace.begin(), str4replace.end());
            // std::cout << org_str << std::endl;
            // std::cout << *i << std::endl;
            j = i + str4find.size();
            // std::cout << *j << std::endl;
            ++find_times;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
    }

    if (org_str.substr(org_str.size() - str4find.size()) == str4find)
    {
        org_str.erase(org_str.size() - str4find.size(), str4find.size());
        org_str.insert(org_str.end(), str4replace.begin(), str4replace.end());
        ++find_times;
    }

    return find_times;
}
```

I update iterator j and i after erase and insert operation, so i think, i and j are not invalid.
Anyone can tell me why the end condition: j != org_str.end() is not work?

**SOLVED!**
Although the cout output is correct, the i iterator is already invalid. Here is the new code. Just change few lines in for-loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int find_and_replace(std::string& org_str, const std::string& str4find, const std::string& str4replace);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::string str("I am a very loooooong string to be process!");
    int find_times;
    find_times = find_and_replace(str, "a", "###");
    std::cout << find_times << std::endl;
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int find_and_replace(std::string& org_str, const std::string& str4find, const std::string& str4replace)
{
    int find_times = 0;

    if (org_str.size() < str4find.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: The original string is too short!" << std::endl;
        return find_times;
    }
    else if (org_str == str4find)
    {
        org_str.assign(str4replace);
        ++find_times;
        return find_times;
    }

    for (auto i = org_str.begin(), j = i + str4find.size(); j != org_str.end(); )
    {
        std::string temp(i, j);
        // std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        if (temp == str4find)
        {
            i = org_str.erase(i, j);

            //CHANGE BEGIN
            //org_str.insert(i, str4replace.begin(), str4replace.end());
            for (auto k = str4replace.begin(); k != str4replace.end(); ++k, ++i)
            {
                i = org_str.insert(i, *k);
            }
            //CHANGE END

            // std::cout << org_str << std::endl;
            // std::cout << *i << std::endl;
            j = i + str4find.size();
            // std::cout << *j << std::endl;
            ++find_times;
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
    }

    if (org_str.substr(org_str.size() - str4find.size()) == str4find)
    {
        org_str.erase(org_str.size() - str4find.size(), str4find.size());
        org_str.insert(org_str.end(), str4replace.begin(), str4replace.end());
        ++find_times;
```

Comment: After `org_str.insert`, `i` and `j` are invalid. You never make `i` valid again and you update `j` relative to the invalid `i`.

Comment: @MikeKinghan At that time, I use std::cout to show *i and *j, the output is correct, so I think i and j both are valid. I made mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` iterator become invalid after calling erase and insert, you should use the return values of that functions or recalculate the position starting from `s.begin()` again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int find_and_replace( string &s, const string &oldVal, const string &newVal ) {
    int find_times = 0;
    if ( s.size() < oldVal.size() ) {
        std::cout << "Error: The original string is too short!" << std::endl;
        return find_times;
    }
    if ( s == oldVal ) {
        s.assign(newVal);
        return ++find_times;
    }
    for ( auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i ) {
        // compare using iterators
        bool is_equal = true;
        auto k = i;
        for ( auto j = oldVal.begin(); j != oldVal.end(); ++j, ++k ) {
            if ( k == s.end() || *j != *k ) {
                is_equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( is_equal ) {
            auto ie = s.erase(i, i + oldVal.size());
            // This may not work with older version of g++
            auto ii = s.insert(ie, std::begin(newVal), std::end(newVal));
            i = ii + newVal.size() - 1;
            ++find_times;
        }
    }
    return find_times;
}

int main() {
    string str("I am a very loooooong string to be process!");
    int find_times;
    find_times = find_and_replace(str, "a", "###");
    cout << find_times << '\n';
    cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output (as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc9ca252d12c2f83)) is:

```
2

I ###m ### very loooooong string to be process!
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! At the begin, I wrote so:i = org_str.insert(org_str.end(), str4replace.begin(), str4replace.end()); But, my compiler tell me the return value of org_str.insert(...) is void. So, i use cout to check if i is invalid. The out put of *i is correct, so I think the i is always valid. Now, I change it to a for-loop:            for (auto k = str4replace.begin(); k != str4replace.end(); ++k, ++i)
            {
                i = org_str.insert(i, *k);
            } Everthing goes well!